# Drawer Adapter Padding in Arabic

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have this navigation drawer adapter which is working great when the language is english, but when the language is arabic some title sections are having margin in the layout is having margin.
here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lay"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/whitelogo"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="2dp"
    android:paddingBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="test"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my adapter:

```
public class DrawerSectionedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


// declaring our ArrayList of items
private ArrayList<DrawerObject> objects;
Activity context;

/* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
* the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Item> objects,
* because it is the list of objects we want to display.
*/
public DrawerSectionedAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DrawerObject> objects) {

    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return objects.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

/*
 * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
 * list item will look.
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (v == null) {
        // Inflate the layout according to the view type
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (type == 0) {
            // Inflate the layout with image
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        } else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.value_item, parent, false);
    }

    DrawerObject i = objects.get(position);
    if (i != null) {

        // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
        // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.
        Typeface typeface = null;
        if (MyApplication.lang.equals("en"))
            typeface = MyApplication.opensansregular;
        else
            typeface = MyApplication.droidregular;
        if (position == 1) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            if (MyApplication.lang.equals("ar"))
                tt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            else
                tt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        }
        if (position == 0) {
            ImageView top = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.top);
            top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lay);
            lay.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            tt.setTypeface(typeface);


        } else {
            if (type == 0) {
                ImageView top = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.top);
                top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            //   ViewResizing.textResize(context,tt,15);
            tt.setText(i.getName());
            tt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tt.setTypeface(typeface);
            RelativeLayout la = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(lay);
            if (MyApplication.lang.equals("en"))
                la.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
            else
                la.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

            if (type != 0) {
                LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear);

                if (i.isLastOne())
                    lin.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                else
                    lin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.undertextline);
            }

        }
        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!

    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (objects.get(position).isTitle()) ? 0 : 1;
}

}
```

here is a screen shot (see ادراجات ... )
[image: see ادراجات]

please help

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED IT

```
public class DrawerSectionedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


// declaring our ArrayList of items
private ArrayList<DrawerObject> objects;
Activity context;

/* here we must override the constructor for ArrayAdapter
* the only variable we care about now is ArrayList<Item> objects,
* because it is the list of objects we want to display.
*/
public DrawerSectionedAdapter(Activity context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<DrawerObject> objects) {

    this.objects = objects;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return objects.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return objects.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

/*
 * we are overriding the getView method here - this is what defines how each
 * list item will look.
 */
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // assign the view we are converting to a local variable
    View v = convertView;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (v == null) {
        // Inflate the layout according to the view type
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (type == 0) {
            // Inflate the layout with image
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        } else
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.value_item, parent, false);
    }

    DrawerObject i = objects.get(position);
    if (i != null) {

        // This is how you obtain a reference to the TextViews.
        // These TextViews are created in the XML files we defined.
        Typeface typeface = null;
        if (MyApplication.lang.equals("en"))
            typeface = MyApplication.opensansregular;
        else
            typeface = MyApplication.droidregular;
        if (position == 1) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            if (MyApplication.lang.equals("ar"))
                tt.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            else
                tt.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        }
        if (position == 0) {
            ImageView top = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.top);
            top.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

            tt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lay);
            lay.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
            tt.setTypeface(typeface);


        } else {

            if (type == 0) {
                ImageView top = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.top);
                top.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                RelativeLayout lay = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lay);
                lay.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue));
            }
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            //   ViewResizing.textResize(context,tt,15);
            tt.setText(i.getName());
            tt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tt.setTypeface(typeface);
            RelativeLayout la = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.lay);
            //la.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.blue));
            if (MyApplication.lang.equals("en"))
                la.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
            else
                la.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

            if (type != 0) {
                LinearLayout lin = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.linear);

                if (i.isLastOne())
                    lin.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.white));
                else
                    lin.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.undertextline);
            }

        }
        // check to see if each individual textview is null.
        // if not, assign some text!

    }

    // the view must be returned to our activity
    return v;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return (objects.get(position).isTitle()) ? 0 : 1;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use
 
`android:paddingStart` instead of `android:paddingLeft` 

and 
`android:paddingEnd` instead of `android:paddingRight`.

This issue is occur when your language is starting form right to left (RTL). So try to use `Start` & `End` instead of `Left` & `Right`.

Let me know, if any problem still persist.